# Converting Datetimeindex of a dataframe to week numbers

Tags: python, week-number, datetimeindex

I am very new to Python and cannot seem to solve the problem on my own. Currently I have a dataset which I already converted to a DataFrame using pandas which has a datetimeindex according to yyyy-mm-dd-HH-MM-SS with time stamps of minutes. The attached figure shows the already interpolated dataframe.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbCwe.png)

Now I want to convert the date/datetimeindex to week numbers to plot the corresponding HVAC Actual, Chiller power etc. to their week number. The index already was set to time but I got an error telling that 'Time' was not recognized in the columns. I tried to recall the index like in the code below and from there create a new column using  dt.week

```
building_interpolated = building_interpolated.set_index('Time')
building_interpolated['Week number'] =
building_interpolated['Time'].dt.week
```

If I am correct this should create a new column called Week number with the week number in it. However, I still get an error telling that ['Time'] is not in the columns (see figure below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l5E1.png)

Anyone who can help me?

Regards, nooby Boaz ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.index = df.index.to_series().dt.isocalendar().week
```

Comment: By this code you convert the datetimeindex to the weeknumber but then in series form if I am understanding it correctly right?

Comment: `.to_series()` is necessary to apply `.dt`. If you want to apply something more linear, you can simply apply `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Time).dt.isocalendar().week ` and then rename the index with `df.index.name = "Time"`

Comment: If you think this solves your problem, accept the answer